# reactjs onclick display component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why isn't my component rendering?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Chokers, Bracelets, FRings, MRings} from './AllItems.js'

    class App extends Component {

      handleClick(e){

        <Chokers chokers={this.props.items.Chokers}/>
      }
      render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ul style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                    <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Chokers</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a><Bracelets bracelets={this.props.items.Bracelets}/>Bracelets</li>
                    <li><FRings frings={this.props.items.FRings}/>Rings for Women</li>
                    <li><MRings mrings={this.props.items.MRings}/>Rings for Men</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Basically my this.props.items.Chokers for examples call a on my json file that was passed through.

I just want to create a links to another component at an onClick event. 
The problem that I am having is that my Component under handleClick doesnt render.

Comment: do you want to make Chokers as the child component of App on onClick ??

Comment: @MayankShukla I would just like to show it. Eventually I will make the rest of the components clickable also. So at onClick show that one and hide the other one, is the kind of logic I am aiming for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to render `Chockers` component on the click of item, then write it like this, create the `state` variable and set it `true` `onClick` of the item:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {render:''}
    }
    handleClick(compName, e){
        console.log(compName);
        this.setState({render:compName});        
    }
    _renderSubComp(){
        switch(this.state.render){
            case 'chockers': return <Chokers/>
            case 'bracelets' : return <Bracelets/>
            case 'rings': return <FRings/>
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ul style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                    <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'chockers')}>Chokers</li>
                    <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'bracelets')}>Bracelets</li>
                    <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'rings')}>Rings for Women</li>
                </ul>
                {this._renderSubComp()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Chokers extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>Inside Chockers</div>
    }
}
class FRings extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>Inside FRings</div>
    }
}
class Bracelets extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>Inside Bracelets</div>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Check the `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ocg4ebdf/

Comment: I I want to make all of them clickable such that only one of them can be shown at a time, how would I do that?

Comment: wait 5 min will give a jsfiddle :)

Comment: still there buddy, I am trying different methods, However I am not able to make it work

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly fine ! I actually found a way too. But your answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You are not rendering anything.You just need to return the Chokers component from render function itself.

create some state variable and set that variable to true so that upon this variable check you can render the Chokers component.

Comment: Even when I put the return before `<Chokers chokers={this.props.items.Chokers}/>` It still doesnt render

Comment: No you are doing wrong.Inside handleclick function you need to do setState which will eventually call render function and your logic needs to be in render function.

Comment: Html what you are returning should be from the render method. So you can put conditions and according to that you can use different render.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Chokers, Bracelets, FRings, MRings} from './AllItems.js'

    class App extends Component {
      var flag;
      handleClick(e){
       flag = true;
       render() {
        return (
        <Chokers chokers={this.props.items.Chokers}/>
);}
      }
      if(!flag){
      render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ul style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                    <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Chokers</li>
                    <li><a href=""></a><Bracelets bracelets={this.props.items.Bracelets}/>Bracelets</li>
                    <li><FRings frings={this.props.items.FRings}/>Rings for Women</li>
                    <li><MRings mrings={this.props.items.MRings}/>Rings for Men</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
      }
}
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: I would like to make all of my `<li>` tags clickable such that whenever the person clicks on it, it render only one component. Afterwards when another one is clicked the current one is set to false and the other one is set to true